# append 2 arrays in a collection view

Tags: arrays, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database, uicollectionview

So I have 2 arrays, 1 being a photoPost array and the other a videoPost array. Now is it possible to display both these arrays in the one collection view at the same time? I tried to use the method below but does not work out. I'm not sure if I'm even doing it right.Much help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

```
var photoPosts = [photoPost]()
var videoPosts = [videoPost]()

func retrieveData(){
let ref = Database.database().reference().child("videoPost").child(uid)
        ref.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
            let dictionary = videoPost(snapshot: snapshot)
            self.videoPosts.append(dictionary)
 })
let ref = Database.database().reference().child(“photoPost").child(uid)
        ref.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
            let dictionary = photoPost(snapshot: snapshot)
            self. photoPosts.append(dictionary)
})
 self.newsfeedCollectionView?.reloadData()
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
 return videoPosts.count + photoPosts.count
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {         
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! newsfeedCollectionViewCell
       cell. photoPost = photoPosts[indexPath.item]
       cell.videoPost = videoPosts[indexPath.item] // fatal error:index out of range 
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: The solution would be is to have a single array and append photo and video to it. Right now it is two array and you are returning both the array count in numberOfItemsInSection and in cellForItem your are trying to get the value with indexPath.item which will cause index out of bound as arrays doesn't have that many objects.

Comment: I also tried putting both arrays into a single array but it wasn't working properly. For example the count would be the sum of objects from the photoPost and videoPost but it would only show objects from photoPosts @Gyanendra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Try this

```
       func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {         
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! newsfeedCollectionViewCell
         if indexPath.item < photoPosts.count {
            cell. photoPost = photoPosts[indexPath.item]
           } else {
             cell.videoPost = videoPosts[indexPath.item-photoPosts.count]
             }
            return cell
            }
```

Comment: ok it works perfectly but when I get out of the view controller and go back in it doesn't reload or append the same. Any suggestions as to why this maybe?

Comment: thanks for accepting. Check your function retrieveData() is calling make sure you put at right place viewDidLoad or ViewWillApear.

Comment: Ok thanks. Do you know a way I could mix both arrays and have them append according to the time they have been posted? For example if  I posted a videoPost 10minutes ago it will show at the top but if I posted a photoPost now it will go above the videoPost. At the moment all the photoPosts array shows first and then the videoPosts